How can I keep navigation active without the particle trail in Genshin Impact
It appears that after the most recent update to Genshin Impact the particle trail associated to in city navigation for quests no longer disappears and the keyboard shortcut "V" will not turn it off... Any ideas on how to get it to go away, or do I need to complain to HoYo Games about this?

As of right now, Sept 5, 2024, my testing seems to show that the answer is still "the particle trail is permanent for the active quest".
You could replicate the effect on the minimap by going to the world map, checking the active quest's location marker and turning it off, but then immediately replacing it with a Custom Pin that you turn on Navigation for.
